# What mutable object really means in Python

Tags: python

I am quite confused about what mutable object really means

```
A=[1,3,4]
print(id(A))
A.append(1)
print(id(A))
```

The print-out shows the same address, while for the following

```
A=[1,3,4]
print(id(A))
A=A+[1,2]
print(id(A))
```

The first thing is that it doesn't report wrong since I expect since it is mutable it will do the iterative procedure, on the other hand, the address is different.

Comment: add some sample output :)

Comment: The fact that a thing *is* mutable doesn't mean that you *actually mutated* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
A = [1,2,3]
A.append(1)
```

you modify the list in place, thus causing no change in its address. On the other hand, when you do

```
A = [1,2,3]
A = A + [1,2]
```

you create a temporary new object `A + [1,2]` and then *re-bind* the existing list `A` to this newly created object (i.e. the newly created list), thus changing its address/id.

Answer (score 1):

The first example mutates the list by calling `append()`. So the `id()` of the object is the same each time.

The second example reassigns the variable `A` to a new list that is the result of concatenating two lists. This does *not* mutate the original list. To see why, let's make a small modification:

```
A=[1,3,4]
print(id(A))
B=A+[1,2]
print(id(A))
print(id(B))
```

Now you will see that the `id(A)` is the same both times. Your original code is equivalent to this other than you no longer have a reference to the first list.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,3]
A.append(4) #just appends new element to list (but does not create new memory address to A)
A = A + [5,6] # first do [1,2,3,4] + [5,6] => [1,2,3,4,5,6], then assign this to A (which is creating and assigning new memory address to A).
```

Answer (score -1):

Mutable objects means a data type that CAN CHANGE for example lists, dictionary, etcetera as you can always append or add values to them.

On the contrary, IMMUTABLE objects are those that CANNOT CHANGE, for example a TUPLE in python.

Hope it helped.

You must use .append() function

Comment: but why '+' method change the address

Comment: @8908 It doesn't. `=` does